# В чем разница байндинга свойств Text и Visibility?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

Скорее всего ответ где-то на поверхности, но я не могу никак да него добраться. 
Почему одно и тоже свойство в одинаковом биндинге работает по-разному для разных контролов?

Есть класс, в котором указано свойство IsBlockScreen для UserControl'a

```
bool _IsBlockScreen;
    public bool IsBlockScreen
    {
        get { return _IsBlockScreen; }
        set 
        {
            _IsBlockScreen = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange("IsBlockScreen");
        }
    }

    public void DoBlockScreen(bool needBlock)
    {
        IsBlockScreen = needBlock;
    }
```

Xaml выглядит так:

```
<UserControl 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
Background="AliceBlue" Padding="10,0,10,0"> 
<UserControl.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibility" />
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ProgressTemplate">
        <Border Background="#FFD5E4F2" OpacityMask="#DB000000">
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=.}" FontSize="14" FontStyle="Italic" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0 5 0 0" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid Width="900">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ContentControl Template="{StaticResource ProgressTemplate}" DataContext="Создание документа" Visibility="{Binding IsBlockScreen, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding IsBlockScreen}" Height="20"/>
</Grid>
```

В первом случае ContentControl остается видимым и дебаггер даже не заходит в геттер свойства. Тогда как TextBlock показывает корректное значение переменной. Соответственно, при вызове функции и изменении IsBlockScreen, текст поменяется, а видимость контрола останется прежней.
В чем подвох?

**UDP:** После различных игр стало понятно, что разница не в свойствах, а в типе контрола. ContentControl игнорирует установку свойства Visibility, тогда как TextBlock будет исчезать, как и положено. Но в чем тут проблема и как ее преодолеть все еще не ясно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в коде

```
DataContext="Создание документа"
```

Дело в том, что `Binding` происходит к `DataContext`'у*. Соответственно если вы меняете его, то и свойство `IsBlockScreen` ищется не в вашем внешнем `DataContext`'е, а в строке `"Создание документа"` (где его, разумеется, нету).

Я бы посоветовал не трогать `DataContext`, а для передачи контента использовать свойство `Content`:

```
<ContentControl
    Template="{StaticResource ProgressTemplate}"
    Content="Создание документа"
    Visibility="{Binding IsBlockScreen, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}"/>
```

(и соответствующим образом изменить `ProgressTemplate`).

---

*За исключением случаев явно указанного `Source` или `ElementName`.

Comment: спасибо! Решило проблему. Остальное поправлю. И спасибо за очень полезную справку.

Comment: @Skarhl: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло!